# Why don’t we train on the test dataset in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, train-test-split

Can somebody explain why we can not train the dataset on the test dataset?

Comment: See https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/86632/why-is-it-wrong-to-train-and-test-a-model-on-the-same-dataset

Comment: The point of having a test set is to have an accurate measure of how well the model will do on unseen data. If you include the test set in the training data, then the test accuracy will be artificially inflated.

Comment: What will be the outcome if you already know the answers to your FINAL EXAM QUESTIONS? You would outperform your classmates, but would you be able to solve a trickier question using the same fundamentals? -> No, cause you didn't learned anything but got some much familiar with the questions and mugged up the answers, *that's why you don't train on your test dataset*.

Comment: You might want to start by reading a high-quality text like Hastie et al *Elements of Statistical Learning*. https://hastie.su.domains/ElemStatLearn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal of dividing our data to train and test is to use test data as a poor representation of what the model will see in the real world. Suppose we train the model on the test data. In that case, we'll optimize our loss (or model) to fit the test data, so we can't get a reasonable estimate of the model performance on unseen data in the wild because the model is optimized for a good performance on test data.

Answer (score 0):

It could be argued that we should do so and then use a bootstrap procedure to estimate by how much we overfit. Our Frank Harrell, for instance, advocates for this, and our Demetri Pananos once [blogged](https://dpananos.github.io/posts/2021/11/blog-post-34/) about it, where he linked to [some debates](https://twitter.com/GaelVaroquaux/status/1293818409197731840) that are worth reading.

The procedure would be as follows.

1. Estimate your model on all of your data, and calculate your metric of interest (mean squared error, for instance).
2. Select points, with replacement, and build the model on those points.
3. Apply the model from step #2 to the entire data set, and calculate your metric of interest.
4. Repeat steps #2 and #3 dozens, hundreds, or thousands of times, storing the metric from step #3 at each iteration.
5. Use bootstrap techniques to get a sense of by how much you overfit when you train on all of the data (confidence interval and/or bias-corrected point estimate).

If you’ve only overfitted by a little (you’ll define what you’re willing to tolerate as “little”), then you can consider your model to work well.

This is available in the `R` function `rms::validate`.